# sklearn's PLSRegression: "ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

When using [`sklearn.cross_decomposition.PLSRegression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_decomposition.PLSRegression.html):

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.cross_decomposition

pls2 = sklearn.cross_decomposition.PLSRegression()
xx = np.random.random((5,5))
yy = np.zeros((5,5) ) 

yy[0,:] = [0,1,0,0,0]
yy[1,:] = [0,0,0,1,0]
yy[2,:] = [0,0,0,0,1]
#yy[3,:] = [1,0,0,0,0] # Uncommenting this line solves the issue

pls2.fit(xx, yy)
```

I get:

```
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_decomposition\pls_.py:44: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  x_weights = np.dot(X.T, y_score) / np.dot(y_score.T, y_score)
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_decomposition\pls_.py:64: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  if np.dot(x_weights_diff.T, x_weights_diff) < tol or Y.shape[1] == 1:
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_decomposition\pls_.py:67: UserWarning: Maximum number of iterations reached
  warnings.warn('Maximum number of iterations reached')
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_decomposition\pls_.py:297: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  if np.dot(x_scores.T, x_scores) < np.finfo(np.double).eps:
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_decomposition\pls_.py:275: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  if np.all(np.dot(Yk.T, Yk) < np.finfo(np.double).eps):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\svn\hw4\code\test_plsr2.py", line 8, in <module>
    pls2.fit(xx, yy)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_decomposition\pls_.py", line 335, in fit
    linalg.pinv(np.dot(self.x_loadings_.T, self.x_weights_)))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py", line 889, in pinv
    a = _asarray_validated(a, check_finite=check_finite)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_util.py", line 135, in _asarray_validated
    a = np.asarray_chkfinite(a)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 613, in asarray_chkfinite
    "array must not contain infs or NaNs")
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

What could be the issue?

I am aware of [scikit-learn GitHub issue #2089](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2089), but since I use scikit-learn 0.16.1 (with Python 2.7.10 x64) this problem should be solved (the code snippets mentioned in the GitHub issue work fine).

Comment: Is this an example you are trying to reproduce or did you define this data? It may be the case that you have an intractable problem, hence you get nans or inf values for some weights, which fail at some later point in the calculation

Comment: @Chris My original data were larger (https://www.dropbox.com/s/zjrz6upfeln07ga/SE-sklearn-PLSR.zip?dl=0), I tried to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is caused by a bug in scikit-learn. I reported it on GitHub: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2089#issuecomment-152753095

Answer (score 17):

Please check if any of your values being passed in are NaN or inf:

```
np.isnan(xx).any()
np.isnan(yy).any()

np.isinf(xx).any()
np.isinf(yy).any()
```

If any of those yields true. Remove the `nan` entries or inf entries. E.g. you can set them to `0` with:

```
xx = np.nan_to_num(xx)
yy = np.nan_to_num(yy)
```

It's also possible for numpy to be fed such large positive and negative and zeroed values, that the equations deep down in the library are producing zeros, Nan's or Inf's.  One workaround, oddly enough, is to send in smaller numbers (say representative numbers between -1 and 1.  One way to do this is by standardization, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36390482/445131

If none of that solves the problem, then you may be dealing with a low level bug in the library your using, or some sort of singularity in your data.  Create an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and post it to stackoverflow or create a new bug report on the library maintaining your software.

Comment: Thanks. Both evaluate False: `np.isnan(xx).any(): False;
np.isnan(yy).any(): False`

Comment: I've narrowed down the issue: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2089#issuecomment-152753095

Comment: Interesting. Your github issue points toward some sort of singularity in the data. These should be handled gracefully by scikit-learn, so the way it is acting now is definitely buggy.

Comment: `nan` and `inf` check can be combined in `np.isfinite()`

Answer (score 2):

I found a tricky little solution that worked for me.

I was doing time series featurization through cesium with this code:

```
timeInput = np.array(timeData)
valueInput = np.array(data)

#Featurizing Data
featurizedData = featurize.featurize_time_series(times=timeInput,
                                                     values=valueInput,
                                                     errors=None,
                                                     features_to_use=featuresToUse)
```

which was resulting in this error:

```
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

for laughs, I checked the lengths and types of the data:

```
data:
70
<class 'numpy.int32'>

timeData: 
70
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

I decided I'd try to convert data types with this one line of code:

```
valueInput = valueInput.astype(float)
```

and it worked, resulting in this code:

```
timeInput = np.array(timeData)
valueInput = np.array(data)
valueInput = valueInput.astype(float)

#Featurizing Data
try:
    featurizedData = featurize.featurize_time_series(times=timeInput,
                                                     values=valueInput,
                                                     errors=None,
                                                     features_to_use=featuresToUse)
```

if you're getting an error like this, give matching datatypes a shot

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the same bug, I silenced this bug by filtering all `0`s away

```
threshold_for_bug = 0.00000001 # could be any value, ex numpy.min
xx[xx < threshold_for_bug] = threshold_for_bug
```

This silences the bug   (i never check the precision difference)

My system info:

```
numpy-1.11.2
python-3.5
macOS Sierra
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check your weights for negative values, since this error will also be triggered with negative weights.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with PRINCE library, for MCA study. My solution was to use "object" dtype, instead of "category". Very frustrating because I spend many hours to find an solution.