# MCA() returns "array must not contain infs or nans"

Tags: python, pandas, pca, mca

I have a dataframe of ones and zeros which act as metadata to describe the properties of some features of the main dataset. As part of a data exploration I was running the following code on the dataframe, to express those features tags into a 2D plot.

```
mca = prince.MCA()
mca_mtx = mca.fit(tags_df).transform(tags_df)
```

But I am getting during the `fit` the following error:

> array must not contain infs or nans

After inspecting the dataframe I see there are no infs or nans in the entire dataset. So the problem must be something else.

Anyone idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is a [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33928382/1773841). The problem is in the values of the dataframe `tags_df`, since `1.0` and `0.0` are producing `inf` or `nan` during the `mca` algorithm.

I tried changing those `1.0` and `0.0` by `True` and `False` (bool type) without success. However, the string version did the trick, that is `"True"` and `"False"`. So the following line solved my problem:

```
tags_df.replace({0: "False", 1: "True"}, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I spend many hours on this error, and luckily found a solution. I've changed the dtype from "category" to "object", using ".astype('object')".
Also I use the following code:

```
    mca = prince.MCA(
    n_components=3,
    n_iter=3,
    copy=True,
    check_input=True,
    engine='sklearn',
    random_state=42
) 
    mca = mca.fit(df_final_2)
    mca.plot(
       df_final_2,
       x_component=0,
       y_component=1
            )
```

Hope it helps!